# grunt js tasks and files naming with multiple dots

Tags: task, gruntjs, minify

I'm uglifying files with one to one mapping like this:

```
    plugins: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: '*.js',
            cwd: 'Scripts/v1/Plugins',
            dest: 'Scripts/v1/Build/Plugins',
            ext: '.min.js'
        }]
    },
```

And this works fine, until i start naming my files with multiple dots in filename.
So above script will uglify 
4 files:
plugins.a.js
plugins.b.js
plugins.c.js
plugins.d.js

into one file:

plugins.min.js

while I expect:

plugins.a.min.js
plugins.b.min.js
plugins.c.min.js
plugins.d.min.js

Is this expected behavior or bug?
In any case how can I keep one to one mapping with my naming convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently the default expected behavior.

This has been brought up a few times with grunt:

- https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/54
- [extension is after *last* period only](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/pull/750)

From the first link, a change has been submitted to [node globule](http://github.com/cowboy/node-globule) that will let you select either first or last dot.

Other than that (or until that lands) you could use a rename function to get the behavior you need.

Answer (score 6):

Did you manage to find a solution for this?
I checked all the issues in their github and apparently it should be fixed, but I'm still getting the same behavior with the latest builds.

EDIT: A solution was to pass a `rename` function and manually create the filename

```
files: {
            src: 'src/hp-lp-<%= pkg.version %>.js',
            dest: 'src/',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            rename: function (dest, src) {
                var folder = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));
                var filename = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/'), src.length);

                filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));

                return dest + folder + filename + '.min.js';
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, I had to manually put all the refs. - was fine for my project as not too many files. P.S.> you should have added this as comment rather than answer.

Comment: Oops sorry, I did find a sollution, you can pass `rename: function (dest, src) {}` and do your own naming logic.

Comment: That's nice, put it as an edit in your answer - I will up-vote.

Comment: Thanks for the example of the rename function, it helped me a good deal!

Answer (score 3):

### Use extDot instead of ext:

In Grunt, this is how your can match filenames with multiple dots **and write to filenames that contain the original dot sequence, except for file extension.**

i.e.

```
/path/to/module.somename.scss -> /path/to/module.somename.css
```

### Example:

```js
files: [{
  expand: true,
  src: ['public_html/**/*.scss'],
  extDot: 'first',
  rename  : function (dest, src) {

    var _new_ext = 'css';

    //Get src filename
    src = src.split("/");
    var filename = src.pop();

    //Apply new extension to filename
    var arr  = filename.split(".");
    arr.pop();
    arr.push(_new_ext);
    filename = arr.join(".");

    dest = dest || src.join("/");

    return dest + '/' + filename;
  }
}]
```

Gist:
https://gist.github.com/tecfu/f84a65ffa850a0bc2e88